# How should I Register a custom UserAccount with MembershipReboot.Owin?

Tags: owin, membershipreboot

Has any one made a multitenant example with a custom useraccount using membershipreboot.owin ?

I Have a hard time figuring out how I should configure the membership middleware when using a custom account. 
Its not covered by the default examples. And I guess i'm not experienced enough with funky Funcs. Any help would be appreciated.

Thx.

The OwinExtentionMethods looks like :

```
     public static class MembershipRebootOwinExtensions
     {
        public static void UseMembershipReboot<TAccount>(
        this IAppBuilder app,
        Func<IDictionary<string, object>, UserAccountService<TAccount>>            userAccountServiceFactory,
        Func<IDictionary<string, object>, AuthenticationService<TAccount>> authenticationServiceFactory = null
        )
        where TAccount : UserAccount
        {
            app.Use<MembershipRebootMiddleware<TAccount>>(userAccountServiceFactory, authenticationServiceFactory);
            app.UseMembershipReboot();
        }

    public static void UseMembershipReboot<TAccount>(
        this IAppBuilder app,
        CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieOptions,
        Func<IDictionary<string, object>, UserAccountService<TAccount>> userAccountServiceFactory,
        Func<IDictionary<string, object>, AuthenticationService<TAccount>> authenticationServiceFactory = null
        )
        where TAccount : UserAccount
        {
            app.Use<MembershipRebootMiddleware<TAccount>>(userAccountServiceFactory, authenticationServiceFactory);
            app.UseMembershipReboot(cookieOptions);
        }
```

How would I fill in the two func's ?

```
    Func<IDictionary<string, object>, UserAccountService<TAccount>>
```

and

```
    Func<IDictionary<string, object>, AuthenticationService<TAccount>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom user account sample has an example of using the generics:

https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/tree/master/samples/CustomUserAccount

Comment: That sample doesn't use Owin! Right?

Comment: No, but it shows in an isolated way how to use a custom user account with all the generics.

Comment: Maybe its my lacking understanding of Func's but the example doesn't help me. It only shows how you instantiate Generic datasource class, generic repository class. My problem is i have a hard time understanding how to supply funcs as the generic parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Simply obtain the current context of owin as

```
var owin = ctx.Resolve<IOwinContext>();
```

Then register your custom useraccount as

```
var owinAuth = new OwinAuthenticationService<CustomUserAccount>(AuthenticationTypes.Negotiate, ctx.Resolve<UserAccountService<CustomUserAccount>>(), owin.Environment);
```

I hope it's not too late.